# Set column type with a select ... into statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to create a table using a SELECT ... INTO statement. The table is created and populates properly, but I want to change the data type of two of the columns.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    AR_Server_Pre.OrderID, 
    AR_Server_Pre.LineTotal, 
    AR_Server_Pre.[Total payments], 
    AR_Server_Pre.ShipDate, 
    (AR_Server_Pre.LineTotal-nz(AR_Server_Pre.[Total Payments])) AS AmountDue 
INTO AR_Final
FROM AR_Server_Pre
WHERE 
    ((([AR_Server_Pre].[LineTotal]-nz([AR_Server_Pre].[Total Payments]))>0.5) 
    AND 
    ((AR_Server_Pre.ShipDate)<Date()));
```

I want to assign column type of currency to LineTotal and AmountDue. AR_Server_Pre is a Select Query, so the simple solution of "Change it at that table) won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the specified fields in a `CCur()` function to force them to be `Currency`, e.g.,

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW 
    AR_Server_Pre.OrderID, 
    CCur(AR_Server_Pre.LineTotal) AS LineTotal, 
...
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I knew it had to be something along those lines, but I couldn't figure out the exact formatting.